# Differences between "in order to", "so that" and "so as to"?

Tags: conjunctions, word-choice

Are there any differences (general or regional differences) between "in order to", "so that" and "so as to"?

I've seen that they may be interchangeable, but I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those are largely similar; however, [from here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv146.shtml) and [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2393312):

- *in order to* and *so as to* are more formal and used before verbs like *know*, *seem*, *understand*: *... I asked in order to know...*.
- *so that* is less formal - and often reduced to *so* in informal use. It also is used with modal verbs like *can*: *... so that I can ...*
- *so that* and *in order to* need a subject/verb: *... I did this so that I could...*

Google Ngrams gives, for American English (red = *so that*, blue = *in order to*, orange = *so as to*):

[image]
and for British English:

[image]

Doesn't look like there is much of a difference between American and British English in that matter.

Comment: Note that these days *in order to* is deprecated in some style guides that recommend *to* instead, which could function exactly as the longer version. It will be difficult to isolate such a use of *to* through nGrams, though.

Answer (score 1):

`verb1` + *to* + `verb2`: `verb2` has simple, direct relationship (usually a purpose) with `verb1`.

> I bought a coke to drink.

`verb1` *so as to* `verb2`: `verb2` is a resulting action one hopes to get from verb1.  Therefore, `verb1` and `verb2` may not directly related in common understanding.

> I work hard in order to save money for a vacation this year.

*In order to* is a formal way of saying *so as to*.