# “Ourself” vs. “Our Self”?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, relative-pronouns

I want to say something such as these quotes:

> "We must acknowledge our weakness, so we could understand the cause and easier to rule our self"

Its mean that we must acknowledge our weakness, so we could understand the root cause of the weakness so it will be easier for us to improve it.

My question: is the above quote right in terms of grammar, particularly in regards to "our self" or "ourself"?

Answer (score 8):

Neither "*ourself*" nor "*our self*", but **ourselves**.

**Our** is the possessive, which comes from the pronoun **we**. It's a rule that the plural of some words ending in **f** or which have **f** as penult will be changed to **ves**. It also happens to words such as *knife* -> *knives* and *wife* -> *wives*.

**Note**: I also edited your question and rewrote your example by following some grammar rules of verbal times.

> We must acknowledge our weakness, so that we can understand the cause and more easily rule ourselves.

If you want to know more about the mistakes I have fixed, take a look at these topics, which are related to the mistakes you made:

- [How to use "so that" and "so"](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/8-9.html)
- [How to use "to" - forming the infinitive](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/infinitive/)

Comment: i read both of link you provide, but seriously my english is not really good, i understand that i need to use `ourselves` but still why i need to remove 'to' ?

Comment: is it wrong to put `to rule`? then what is the different between `to rule` and `to eat`.

Comment: "We can easier rule ourselves" isn't fluent, because we need an adverb to modify the verb *rule*.  The more fluent way to put it would be "we can **more easily** rule ourselves."

Comment: ...or, alternatively, "we can make it easier to rule ourselves." David, you were correct that the original was ungrammatical, but, unfortunately, your edit was also ungrammatical.

Comment: So this sentence is correct ? "We must acknowledge our weakness, so we could understand the cause and easier to rule ourselves".

Comment: @J.R Oh, yes, I have already fixed it, I didn't pay attention to these details, as stagdon mentioned, sorry.

Comment: @Tengku - no, not quite. It's got a lot of problems. Maybe I should write an answer.

Comment: @Tengku Actually, no. Have you checked the link I sent you about _So that_ ? You used "We must acknowledge our weakness _so that_ we could.." You should've written: _so that we can.._ Your sentence seems to be in the present tense, so "could" wouldn't be suitable for this verbal time,  _Could_ might be placed in sentences which started in the past, like: _We should acknowledge our weakness so that we could.._ Or: _We might acknowledge our weakness so that we could.._

Comment: Davyd is right: It should be _can_ and it can't be _could_.

Comment: i see, now it make sense.

Comment: Is it possible to make sentence more shorter but the meaning is still same ? like `We must acknowledge our weakness, to understand the cause and rule ourselves`, something like that.

Comment: I can't give comments so only through this to say mine "We must acknowledge our weakness **in order** to understand the cause and rule ourselves"

Comment: @Tengku  _We must acknowledge our weakness, in order to understand the cause and more easily rule ourselves_. There you are. _in order to_ = _so that_ but when it is used, no nouns must be proceeded after _to_. See the diferences: _We must acknowledge our weakness, 'so that' 'we' can understand the cause and more easily rule ourselves_ - _We must acknowledge our weakness, 'in order to understand' the cause and more easily rule ourselves_. If you want to understand more about in order to x so that: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/134/differences-between-in-order-to-so-that-and-so-as-to.

Answer (score 3):

On the "proofreading" front, note that you'd need something like *...so we **can** understand the cause, **making it** easier to...* (OP's text as presented is simply ungrammatical at the highlighted points).

Regarding the choice between *to rule ourselves* and *to rule our self*, there's a certain amount of "wiggle room". But the situation is complicated by the fact that there are two significantly different semantic nuances that *don't* correspond to the simplistic "grammatical / logical" distinctions.

Ordinarily, *We must rule ourselves* (single-word reflexive form) will be understood as meaning that ***we*** (not someone else) must be in charge of our affairs. But consider...

> *We must not let our [**head** rule our **heart**.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22our%20head%20rule%20our%20heart%22)*

There will always be pedants who insist that should be ***heads*** and ***hearts*** (which is admittedly [more common](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22our%20heads%20rule%20our%20hearts%22)), but [as I have pointed out on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15322/on-their-back-or-on-their-backs), I'm not one of them. So from my point of view...

> *In order to truly exercise self-control, we must learn to rule our self*

...is a perfectly valid construction. *And* it has the advantage of putting plenty of syntactic distance between the two different possible meanings:

> 1: *to rule oneself rather than being ruled by others*
>    or
>    2: *to rule one's **self = id = ego** as opposed to controlling, say, one's appetite, or children.*

---

TL;DR: It depends what *meaning* you intend, but if you want #2 above there are strong arguments for using the singular form in this *exact* context, because even if you explicitly write it as two words, the reader is likely to be misled into assuming sense #1.

Note that this isn't so much of a problem in *speech*, where you stress ***self/selves*** for sense #2.

Comment: Most important point that i try to brings up is `1. Acknowledge our weakness`, so we able to figure out the root cause problem `2.Understand the cause` , in order to make a change `3.rule ourselves`.

Comment: what if i said "In order to rule ourselves, we must know the cause by acknowledge our weakness".

Comment: @Tengku: I don't understand what you mean. Do *you* understand the difference between the two possible meanings I've outlined above?

Comment: Not really, but tomorrow i will show your answer to my friend, so that he can explain to me.

Comment: @Tengku: Do you understand the normal use of reflexive pronouns? For example, if I say it might be better *if I explain it to you **myself***, do you see how including the highlighted word implies I think it should be ***me*** (specifically me, *not* your friend) who does the explaining?

Comment: yes, i am trying to say no 1 that you mention. I will show to my colleague tomorrow morning and will ask him to explain all your statement above.

Comment: @Tengku: If you intend the first meaning (i.e. - you're *not* thinking in terms of each of us having an internal ["super-ego"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id,_ego_and_super-ego) that must be controlled), there's no scope for using either of the two-word forms - you can *only* use the single-word reflexive pronoun form ***ourselves***. Although I have defended it above, the two-word singular form ***our self*** would be unusual / non-standard in *any* context, and it certainly doesn't apply to the meaning you're trying to express here.

Comment: @Tengku I think the difference FumbleFingers is pointing out is whether you want to say that 1) all of us together need to acknowledge the weaknesses in us *as a group* so that we can rule ***ourselves** as a group*, or instead 2) each of us individually needs to acknowledge our (separate, individual) faults so we can each rule ***our** (own individual) **self***.

Comment: @1006a: That's pretty much it. Specifically, the difference is that *both* the two-word forms explicitly reference some kind of "internal self" (per [the homunculus argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homunculus_argument)) that needs to be controlled, whereas the single-word reflexive pronoun version carries no such implication. That's to say *Control yourself!* is both syntactically and semantically similar to *Behave yourself!*, but whereas you could feasibly say *Control your self!* in certain contexts, it simply makes no sense to say *Behave your self!* in *any* context.

Comment: after read so many times, i came up with "We must acknowledge our weakness, in order to understand the cause and making it easier to rule our self" , is it right ?, i am using 'our self' because as @1006a said, i want it to be our (own individual) self instead of a group.

Comment: @Tengku: I don't know what "cause" your example refers to (or what real-world outcome that causative agent actually brought about), so I still don't know *exactly* what you mean by "self", and how it relates to that cause. But if you don't want to create unnecessary confusion because of unwanted associations with the reflexive pronoun ***ourselves***, why not just use a different word for whatever it is we need to bring under control? *Ego, psyche, "inner person"*, etc. Or identify a characteristic *(control our greed?)*. Or explicitly separate the problematic bits *(our innermost selves)*.